# JavaScript can't select DOM element by ID in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a way for JavaScript to interact with the DOM on a WordPress page. Or is interaction only possible through jQuery?

Button element in `header.php`:

```php
<div id="settings" class="special-menu__item btn-settings">
            <button class="special-menu__title">
              <i style="margin-right: 10px" class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        Настройки
    </button>
</div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```js
const settingButton = document.getElementById("settings");
let toggle = false;
settingButton.addEventListener("click", function _f() {
  if (toggle === false) {
    settingButton.classList.add("active");
    settingOpen.classList.add("open");
  } else {
    settingButton.classList.remove("active");
    settingOpen.classList.remove("open");
  }
  toggle = !toggle;
  removeEventListener("click", _f);
});
```

Comment: Interaction is possible with plain JavaScript as well. Can you show us how you've tried to select the DOM element?

Comment: @hoargarth Yes. I want to get an element with ID "settings", `const settingButton = document.getElementById("settings");`, and then add an EventListener to it, but the console says the element is null

Comment: This sounds like your javascript is being executed before the element exists. We definitely need more information about the element you want to select. Maybe some code or plugin which is responsible for the element etc. Please update your question with any new information

Comment: @Hoargarth, The post was updated, I hope this information will help

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue too.

In the console, I could grab any element I wanted with getElementById or querySelector. But when I would select it in my custom JS code, it would be null.

To get around this, you can just add your code in a load event listener. This way, after the page loads, you can run your code and change the DOM element how you want.
It might not be the most functional thing to watch, but it works.

example:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const element = document.querySelector('#elementId');
    console.log('element I selected:', element)
})
```